# jQuery inluclude still seems ncessary for script to work within post

Tags: posts, jquery

I have a jQuery script that works fine within a WordPress post as long as I include a reference to the jQuery libarary within the post.

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>`

From what I have read this is not the proper way to reference jQuery as it is already included within WordPress (using v3.4.2).

If I remove the inline reference the script fails and the console says that "$" is undefined. I also tried replacing "$" with "jQuery" according to articles that talk about NoConflict mode in jQuery.

My jQuery script can be viewed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/webworm/uCS3P/) in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use $ inside your script (You only need to change the wrapper of your script), use the following wrapper.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
});
```

Make sure you enqueue jQuery in one of your plugins or theme using `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');`

Read more on Codex

> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

The following article contains useful tips on using jQuery with WordPress.

> http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/

Comment: +1 Thanks! That worked great. I changed the wrapper of the script and added the `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` to my functions.php file in my theme using the method explained in WP codex link you posted.